# Actionbuttons work after the second time they are pressed in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below with 3 actionButtons. I want every time a user presses any of them a different pair of images should be displayed. The images are already saved  in a folder named `www` inside my working directory.  And they are named like:

```
"1betA_green.jpg"
"1betA_green.jpg"
```

Default case when the user opens the app.

```
"2betA_green.jpg"
"2betA_green.jpg"
```

for 1st time the user press any `actionButton()`.

etc..

This can happen up to 6 times then it stops. The issue is that when I open the app the first time that I press an actionbutton it does move instantly to the second pair of images but I have to press it again.

```
library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    id="main",
    title="Risk and ambiguity",
    useShinyjs(),

    #when you press on of the 3 actionbuttons for first-example
    fluidRow(wellPanel(
      splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), column(6,uiOutput("image1")), column(6,uiOutput("image2"))
                  # column(12,img(src="1betA_green.jpg", height="80%", width="80%", align="left")),
                  # column(12,img(src="1betB_green.jpg", height="80%", width="80%", align="right"))
                  ))),

    #when you press on of the 3 actionbuttons for second time-example
    #fluidRow(wellPanel(
    # splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
    #            column(12,img(src="2betA_green.jpg", height="80%", width="80%", align="left")),
    #           column(12,img(src="2betB_green.jpg", height="80%", width="80%", align="right"))))),

    ####
    fluidRow(wellPanel(
      splitLayout(cellWidths = c("33%", "33%", "33%"),
                  #uiOutput("myactions")
                  column(12,align="center",actionButton("action11", label = "Je choisis option A")),
                  column(12,align="center",actionButton("action12", label = "Je choisis le sac avec A et B")),
                  column(12,align="center",actionButton("action13", label = "Je choisis option B"))
      )))
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session){
    rv <- reactiveValues(img11=NULL, img12=NULL)

    myimage1 <- c("YBS.png", "mouse.png","EC.jpg", "man_log.png", "cube.png", "hotdog.png")
    myimage2 <- c("man_log.png", "cube.png", "hotdog.png", "YBS.png", "mouse.png","EC.jpg")

    output$image1 <- renderUI({tags$img(src=rv$img11, height = "50px")})
    output$image2 <- renderUI({tags$img(src=rv$img12, height = "50px")})
    
    observe({
      nclick <- sum(as.numeric(input$action11) + as.numeric(input$action12) + as.numeric(input$action13))
     
      if (nclick==0) { ###  initial display
        rv$img11=myimage1[1]
        rv$img12=myimage2[1]  
      }else if (nclick>0 & nclick<7){
        rv$img11 <- myimage1[nclick]
        rv$img12 <- myimage2[nclick]
      }else{
        rv$img11 <- NULL
        rv$img12 <- NULL
      }
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: when you open it is showing the first pair - `rv$img11=myimage1[1]` (default, as you requested).  After the first click, it is still showing the first pair as in `rv$img11 <- myimage1[nclick]`.  If you have a different pair of images to open initially, please assign that where it states `if (nclick==0){...}`.  That means you will need 7 pairs of images.

Comment: what if it is changed in a way that the first click shows the 2nd pair, the second click the 3rd etc... The first pair will just be displayed by default and will not have any connection with the buttons. I edited my Q accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
  if (nclick==0) { ###  initial display
    rv$img11=myimage1[1]
    rv$img12=myimage2[1]  
  }else if (nclick>0 & nclick<6){
    rv$img11 <- myimage1[nclick+1]
    rv$img12 <- myimage2[nclick+1]
  }else{
    rv$img11 <- NULL
    rv$img12 <- NULL
  }
```

Comment: the first pair should be displayed by default.Now nothing is displayed when you open the app.

Comment: I made it work with 6 images and if (nclick==0) { ###  initial display
      rv$img11=myimage1[1]
      rv$img12=myimage2[1]  
    }else if (nclick>0 & nclick<7){
      rv$img11 <- myimage1[nclick+1]
      rv$img12 <- myimage2[nclick+1]

Comment: yeah that is what I was commenting right now

Comment: I have created another Q based on your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669254/hide-everything-in-shiny-page-and-replace-it-with-text-after-pressing-any-action